# How to protect the apps script code from users who make a copy of the google sheets it is bound to?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

First of all, I'm not a developer. I made a tool in my free time using apps script in a google spreadsheet with the help of internet. It is a set of menus in the toolbar which helps users to streamline the process of organising their project and task names. Now it is ready to be shared to my colleagues, but I don't want them to see, copy or edit the source code. How can I limit their access to the code?

I tried to lock the sheet, but since I'm sharing with them a template sheet, which they have to make a copy of, the code is accessible from apps script. I found some solutions from the internet which is to deploy it as an add-on or web app. But since, it is to be used in the work domain and will be used by 100s of users, I cannot publish it atm. Is there any other workaround to protect or hide the code from the users?

Thanks in advance!